# Should input validation be client-side or server-side for Enterprise applications?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

I know maybe there's question about validation in client or server.
but this one for Enterprise applications such as Sales, Clients systems

Should the input validation like number, strings, dates be in client-side ? or strongly be in both ? or in server-side only.

***Reason of asking is :***

1. **I see some professional accountants** who can change some of input tags by **Inspect** browser. some of them change the change the **debit** value of transaction which is limited by client-side validation.
2. **Some guys** who works as end-users also try to change dates to previous duration by **Inspect** ( do something in client )  ! and that not allowed and all web-based make these validation from client-side.

In server-side validations example( Check for **branch** if exists, check if **Store** Exists. no problem happened at these scenarios because its server-side already. ) i don't speak about these points ( which related to Database things )

Again. *sorry for asking question as this.* but please give opinions from people who works on Enterprise solutions will help me to take a choice.

Comment: Client-side validation is to make it clear to the user what is expected. All submitted information **absolutely must be verified at the server**.

Comment: Client side validation is great for the 99.9% of users who want to enter correct information. It improves their experience by telling them instantly when something is wrong. But some users want to enter incorrect information. Like you give them a list of values and then they edit the HTML so that they can post a wrong value, either just for fun or to do something evil. Or they can just send requests using Postman or something and sidestep your client-side validation.

Comment: What about doing ajax-server-side validation as client-side ? does this make sense

Comment: Pointy, does you mean date validation also must be in server-side ? if that date is very important and cannot be previous duration ? but useless fields that just hold any values should be at client-side ?

Comment: @Pointy ! can you answer the comment !

Comment: NO.  **ALL** fields posted with forms (or in GET URLs) **must** be validated at the server.

Comment: Look you've had lots of responses with people telling you that everything has to be checked at the server. What's hard to understand about that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Always** validate **all** user data on the server side. Like in **ALWAYS** and **ALL**.

Client side validation is only for UX.

Edit: added *all*.

P.S.: You can't trust the user
P.P.S.: You ***cannot*** trust the user!!! I might not even be a user sitting at his desk in front of the screen. It might just be a software that tries to breach your form. And by *it might* I really mean *it will*! There are thousands of crawlers out there that eventually will attack your system.

Comment: i mean special fields like ( Debit Value, limited number of it ). dates ( which sometimes cannot be previous duration ) and things that should be made in client-side ? should made it in Server-side.

Comment: @kokowawa Was "_Always validate user data on the server side_" not clear?

Comment: @kokowawa your server software cannot even tell whether client-side checking is happening.  Your server has no idea what the client is; it may not be a browser.

Comment: i guess if an example using asp.net mvc. am absolutely zero skill at it now. ;p

Comment: @yunzen Ok, you are chosen one ! So you mean important numerics, dates must be in Server-side ? but acting as client-side validation in browser ? isn't that what you mean